# How to get Zurb Foundation's Reveal/Modal to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I have a very simple page that simply has the following HTML, copied from the Zurb Foundation site:

```
 <p><button class="button" data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</button></p>

    <div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
      <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
      <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
      <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
      <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

I added JQuery and the Foundation .js and .css files from the CDN:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.6.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.6.3/dist/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

But the modal still doesn't fire.

I then added `Foundation.core.min.js`, with no luck. Then `foundation.reveal.min.js` also with no result.

I then tried to add a bunch of util .js files

```
foundation.util.keyboard.js
foundation.util.touch.js
foundation.util.triggers.js
foundation.util.mediaQuery.js
foundation.util.motion.js
```

Still with no result or errors in the console.

Am I missing something here? What can I do to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to initialise Foundation in JS

```
$(document).foundation();
```